# How to change DataTable Pagination Text?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to change Pagination Text Previous to Prev

How is this possible?

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-Permission">
    --------
</table>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.datatable-Permission:not(.ajaxTable)').DataTable({ 
      buttons: dtButtons,
      language: {
        paginate: {
            previous: 'Prev',
            next:     'Next'
        },
        aria: {
            paginate: {
                previous: 'Previous',
                next:     'Next'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Not working!!!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Vadivel123/ch9fxt8w/5/

Comment: The code in your question works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/L7v2xwpu/.

Comment: Should work. But why not for me!

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V6sXmNvqbF/

Full code

Comment: remove not() selector from your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am using DataTables 1.10.13. for me, the blow configuration worked:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "First page", // This is the link to the first page
                    "sPrevious": "Previous page", // This is the link to the previous page
                    "sNext": "Next page", // This is the link to the next page
                    "sLast": "Last page" // This is the link to the last page
                }
```